# Pass a variable to attribute name for input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input text that receives a number of people, and according to this number adds inputs texts for each one. I have a for loop that takes care of that. It also adds an span with the correct person number next to each input text.

But I'm having problems when using the same variable in the name attribute for each input text. I get the last number in each input text (when it should be incremental).

So, then the input text with id `p19_sub_1` changes its value, the function adds the total number of input text according to this value.

How to programmatically set the correct name attribute, like: `p18_sub_1_X` where "X" is should change from 1 to n (`#p19_sub_1 value`)?

```js
$("#p19_sub_1").change(function() {

  $("#contenedor_de_personas").empty()

  var totalp = $("#p19_sub_1").val();
  var initial = 1;

  for (totalp; initial <= totalp; initial++) {
    // Runs 5 times, with values of step 0 through 4.

    console.log(initial);

    $("#contenedor_de_personas").append('<p><span>Persona ' + String(initial) + ':</span><input type="text" class="inp-text-personas" name="" value="" data-tipo="0"></p>')

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor_de_pregunta_19">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <h5 class="orange-text">18. ¿CUÁLES SON LOS NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS DE CADA UNA DE LAS PERSONAS QUE DURMIERON AQUÍ, LA NOCHE ANTERIOR AL DÍA DEL CENSO? (NO OLVIDE REGISTRAR A LOS RECIÉN NACIDOS, ANCIANOS Y VISITAS).
      </h5>

      <h6>Registre a las personas en el orden que se indica a continuación:</h6>
      <ul>
        <li>Jefe o jefa del hogar</li>
        <li>Hijos/as, hijastros/as y/o hijos/as</li>
        <li>Esposa/o o compañera/o</li>
        <li>Adoptivos/as solteros/as con hijos/as</li>
        <li>Hijos/as, hijastros/as y/o hijos/as</li>
        <li>Hijos/as, hijastros/as y/o hijos/as adoptivos.</li>
        <li>Adoptivos/as solteros/as sin hijos/as</li>
        <li>casados/as o unidos/as y su familia</li>
        <li>Yerno / nuera</li>
        <li>Nieto/a</li>
        <li>Padres y/o suegros</li>
        <li>Otros/as parientes: tíos/as, hermanos/as, etc.</li>
        <li>Trabajador/a del hogar.</li>
        <li>Pensionista</li>
        <li>Otras personas no parientes del/de la jefe/a: amigos(as), compadres, etc.</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <p>
      <span>Total personas:</span>
      <input type="text" name="tipo_vivi" id="p19_sub_1" value="total_personas" placeholder="#" data-tipo="0">
    </p>

    <div id="contenedor_de_personas">

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 left-align">
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-de-retroceso" data-posicion-de-pregunta="18">Retroceso<i
                    class="material-icons left">skip_previous</i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <button type="submit">enviar</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6g5sa3c/1/)

Comment: I think your Fiddle was just missing the jQuery library. I added it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had to change from:

```
 $("#contenedor_de_personas").append('<p><span>Persona ' + String(initial) + ':</span><input type="text" class="inp-text-personas" name="" value="" data-tipo="0"></p>')
```

to:

```
$("#contenedor_de_personas").append('<p><span>Persona ' + String(initial) + ':</span><input type="text" class="inp-text-personas" name="p18_sub1_' + initial + '" value="" data-tipo="0"></p>')
```